# reading data from message queue by ascending order

Tags: c++, c, linux, ipc, message-queue

I am using system V message queue. In my program one thread continuously add data to message queue and another thread take out the data from the message queue.

my message queue structure format is

```
struct mymsgbuf {
    long mtype;
    char mtext[MAX_SEND_SIZE];
};
```

when i taking `mtext` from message i need to get the data in ascending order depends on `tag`.

my message queue receive

```
q_ret = msgrcv(msgqueue_id, (struct mymsgbuf *)&recvbuf, MAX_SEND_SIZE, 0, 0)
```

above format return from the first data send into the message queue.

Is there any technique to receive message queue in ascending order?

Comment: Have you tried posix messages ("man mq_overview"), it has a priority associated with each message. The problem is that you can have 32768 different priorities in the linux implementation of posix message queues.

Comment: problem with posix message queue is we can only store 10 message, so data loss will happen if we don't read the data from queue,  minimum i need to save 25 messages in queue

Comment: You can change the message limit by changing /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max

Answer (score 0):

If `tag` is an integer (or can be converted to one) then that is what the mtype field is for.  You just use `tag` as a `type`.

On the `msgrcv` you specify what type you want to read in the 4th parameter.  As a rule you don't want to block if there isn't a message of that type to be read so you should also use the `IPC_NOWAIT` flag.  So to read type/tag 2 it would be:

```
q_ret = msgrcv(msgqueue_id, (struct mymsgbuf *)&recvbuf, MAX_SEND_SIZE, 2, IPC_NOWAIT);
```

There are some other games you can play reading the mtypes e.g. read the first message in the queue that is *not* type 2

```
q_ret = msgrcv(msgqueue_id, (struct mymsgbuf *)&recMSG_EXCEPTvbuf, MAX_SEND_SIZE, 2, IPC_NOWAIT | MSG_EXCEPT);
```

These are described on the msgrcv man page.  If you find your type schemes becoming too complicated it's a sign you might want to bite the bullet and use some other kind of IPC or data structure.